# Extra undefined options for select box in JSON retrieval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a dropdown which has to be populated with the ajax response. I am getting extra undefined options in my dropdown.

**Frequency dropdown:**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="frequenies">Frequencies:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <select name="frequencies" id="frequencies-list" class="form-control">
               <option value="">Select an option</option>
            </select>          
        </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax Response:**

```
success: function(data){
       alert(data);
       var x = JSON.parse(data);
       $.each(x, function() {
            $.each(this, function(k, v) {
              var frequencies = "<option value="+v.freq+">"+v.freq+"</option>";
              $(frequencies).appendTo('#frequencies-list');
           });
        });
}
```

**data variable is an encoded JSON:**

```
[[{"freq":"1"},{"freq":"3"},{"freq":"6"},{"freq":"12"},{"freq":"24"},{"freq":"36"},{"freq":"48"},{"freq":"60"},{"freq":"72"},{"freq":"96"},{"freq":"120"},{"freq":"144"}],[{"ad_size_full":"Tab Page"},{"ad_size_full":"BRC's"},{"ad_size_full":"Cover tip"}],[{"ad_size_fractional":"2\/3 Page"},{"ad_size_fractional":"1\/2 Page Island"},{"ad_size_fractional":"1\/2 Page"},{"ad_size_fractional":"1\/3 Page"},{"ad_size_fractional":"1\/4 Page"},{"ad_size_fractional":"1\/6 Page"}],[{"color":"B&W"},{"color":"2 Color"},{"color":"3  Color \/ 4 color"},{"color":"5 Color"},{"color":"Matched Color"},{"color":"Matalic Color \/ PMS 800"}],[{"charge":"0.000000"},{"charge":"0.250000"},{"charge":"0.100000"},{"charge":"0.500000"},{"charge":"0.150000"},{"charge":"0.150000"},{"charge":"0.100000"}]]
```

v.freq produces extra  "undefined" options in my dropdown. May I can get help?

```
1
3
6
12
24
36
48
60
72
96
120
144
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you need is only the frequency right? how about this way:

```
$.each(x, function() {
    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
      if ("freq" in v) {
          var frequencies = "<option value="+v.freq+">"+v.freq+"</option>";
          $(frequencies).appendTo('#frequencies-list');
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the next sub `array`, there is no index `freq`. Try -

```
    $.each(x, function() {
        $.each(this, function(k, v) {
          if (typeof v.freq != 'undefined') {
              var frequencies = "<option value="+v.freq+">"+v.freq+"</option>";
              $(frequencies).appendTo('#frequencies-list');
          }
       });
    });
```

Or loop through only the first sub-array.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

```
   $.each(x, function() {
            $.each(this, function(k, v) {
              if (v.freq) // will check for undefined, null, isNaN
               {
                  var frequencies = "<option value="+v.freq+">"+v.freq+"    </option>";
                  $(frequencies).appendTo('#frequencies-list');
              }
           });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping the inner loop with the 1st element of the object.

```
$.each(x, function() {
                $.each(x[0], function(k, v) {
                      var frequencies = "<option value="+v.freq+">"+v.freq+"</option>";
                      $(frequencies).appendTo('#frequencies-list');
               });
            });
```